# Hotkey to post answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, keyboard-shortcuts

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> while editing any post will commit the edit.

Can we have the same hotkey while typing a new answer (instead of having to press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)?

Comment: I'm glad `<kbd>` is back on meta.

Comment: If I use tab + enter, I am sent to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I mean from within the answer box, after you finish typing.

Comment: If I do it from the "Your Answer" text area, I highlight the browser's text box for the URL.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2. Actually, not even "control + tab" has the effect you are describing, for me; I even tried using another modifier, instead of the control key, but the effect is always the same: I move the text cursor to a new line.

Comment: It works for me on Windows.  You just made my question stronger, since Mac users can't even use Tab, Enter.